# Como mover una imagen en Python sin detener el bucle principal en un juego?

Tags: python, hilos, multitasking

Como mover una imagen en Python sin detener el bucle principal en un juego?

Tengo un juego en Python y en un momento quiero que durante al partida aparezca una imagen se mantenga unos segundos y se vaya sin que afecte la partida. Lo que me pasa es que cuando hago aparecer la imagen toda la partida se detiene hasta que la imagen haga lo suyo para luego continuar.

No se si necesito saber algo de multiprocesos o que, estoy empezando en Python. Muchas gracias desde ya.

Comment: Cómo haces que la imagen "se mantenga unos segundos"? Quizás has metido un `sleep()`? Eso detendría el bucle principal. Lo que deberías hacer sería poner la imagen y programar un temporizador para N segundos después, de modo que cuando el teporizador expire se ejecute una función que vuelva a quitar la imagen.

Comment: A que te refieres con un temporizador? como lo creas? Gracias.

Comment: Pues no has dicho qué motor estás usando para hacer el juego, pero prácticamente todos tienen algún mecanismo similar a lo que he llamado "temporizador", que básicamente permite meter una función al bucle de eventos junto con un valor de tiempo. El bucle de eventos se ocupará de llamar a esa función una vez transcurrido ese tiempo. En tu caso la idea sería, desde la función que pone la imagen, llamar a esa utilidad para meter en la cola de eventos la función que ha de quitar la imagen más tarde.

Answer (score 0):

¿Puedes ofrecer más información como framework usado, si es una interfaz, etc etc?
En principio lo normal es usar un thread para realizar ese tipo de actividades sin que paralicen el hilo principal del programa.

```py
import threading
import turtle

def imagenMov(vent, imag):
    vent.tracer(1)
    imag.showturtle()
    imag.speed(4)
    imag.goto(380, -290)
    imag.goto(500, -500)
    vent.tracer(0)

# Ventana
ventana = turtle.Screen()
ventana.setup(900, 700)
ventana.tracer(0)
ventana.register_shape("imagen.gif")

# Imagen
imagen = turtle.Turtle()
imagen.speed(1)
imagen.shape("imagen.gif")
imagen.penup()
imagen.hideturtle()
imagen.goto(500, -500)


while True:
    if condicion para que la imagen se mueva:
        image_thread = threading.Thread(target=imagenMov, args=(ventana, imagen), daemon=True)
        image_thread.start()
    # Abajo continuaria el resto del codigo
```

Comment: No estoy usando un framework, estoy con el modulo Turtle creando una interfaz para un juego, y en mi bucle principal tengo una condición la cual si se cumple, llama a una función para que la imagen se mueva, la cosa es que cuando se ejecuta esa función, la imagen se mueve en un intervalo de tiempo en el cual todo el programa queda pausado incluido el bucle principal, y el juego no seguirá hasta que la función pare, lo que necesito es encontrar una forma de ejecutar esa función sin que influya en el bucle principal del juego. Gracias

Comment: @Gabiygian ¿puedes facilitar el fragmento de código que usas para que la imagen se mueva? En la función que he puesto, tienes un esquema básico del funcionamiento de un thread, si me muestras cómo lo estás haciendo, puedo modificarla para que se adapte a lo que necesitas.

Comment: Si, te he escrito el código simplificado arriba

Comment: Perdona la demora, cuéntame qué te parece esta forma. No he trabajado con Turtle, así que sé si es compatible con multithreading, pero lo que he puesto debería mostrarte el camino de cómo debería ser. @Gabiygian

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas multiprocesos ni multihilos. Pero no debes nunca acaparar el flujo de ejecución en una función que tarde mucho en retornar, pues hasta que esa función no retorne el resto del programa (la interfaz de usuario) no se podrá ejecutar y por tanto parecerá todo "congelado".

Es decir si quieres que una función repita un ciclo de animación que va a durar por ejemplo 3 segundos, no puedes hacer que esa función acapare la ejecución durante esos 3 segundos.

El truco es pintar un "trocito" de esa animación para poder retornar cuanto antes, y preparar un temporizador para que unos cuantos milisegundos después llame otra vez a esa función para que pueda pintar otro "trocito" de animación (y desde ella otra vez se prepara el temporizador para que vuelva a ser llamada unos milisegundos después, etc.) Así, entre llamada y llamada, el bucle de eventos principal puede entrar y atender otros eventos de la interfaz.

## Ejemplo

Es difícil darte un ejemplo útil sin saber qué hace el resto de tu programa "mientras tanto", pero a modo de ejemplo muestro uno que "anima" una imagen (la bombilla que salta) mientras el programa principal dibuja una flor en respuesta a un clic del ratón.

Para implementar la "animación" de la imagen he hecho mi propia clase, que pinta un "fotograma" cada 20ms, y que tiene métodos para arrancar y parar la animación (que no hacen más que cambiar un booleano). La animación en sí se logra modificando la coordenada `y` y programando una nueva actualización 20ms después, haciendo uso de `ventana.ontimer()`

```
import turtle

# Ventana
ventana = turtle.Screen()
ventana.setup(500, 200)
ventana.register_shape("imagen.gif")

# Imagen
class Animacion:
    def __init__(self, fichero, tiempo=20):
        self.imagen = turtle.Turtle()
        self.imagen.shape(fichero)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.vel_y = 4
        self.animating = False
        self.tiempo = tiempo

    def fotograma(self):
        self.imagen.goto(self.x, self.y)
        turtle.update()

    def animacion(self):
        if not self.animating:
            return
        self.fotograma()
        self.y += self.vel_y
        if self.y >= 50 or self.y <= 0:
            self.vel_y = -self.vel_y
        ventana.ontimer(self.animacion, self.tiempo)

    def start(self):
        self.animating = True
        self.animacion()

    def stop(self):
        self.animating = False

# Lanzamos la animación
anim = Animacion("imagen.gif")
anim.start()

# Y ya que retorna pronto, podemos ir haciendo otra cosa
# (que será interrumpida cada 500 ms para hacer otro salto
def dibuja_estrella(x, y):
    turtle.speed(10)
    turtle.goto(x-100,y)
    ventana.tracer(1)
    for _ in range(36):
        turtle.forward(200)
        turtle.left(170)
    ventana.tracer(0)
    # Cuando se termine este dibujo, la imagen deja de saltar
    anim.stop()

turtle.onscreenclick(dibuja_estrella)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Y este es el resultado, la animación comienza inmediatamente, pero la interfaz no está congelada. Cuando pincho con el ratón se ejecuta el dibujo de la flor (en "paralelo" con la animación que continúa, hasta que la flor termina).

[image: Animacion]

Si estás pensando que esto es complejo y tedioso, te doy la razón. Turtle no está pensado para estas cosas. Mejor usar un *framework* para videojuegos como Pygame.